# iMacros URL extraction issue - Java Script EVAL solution needed

Tags: javascript, url, eval, imacros, extract

Running a iMacros script via the iMacros browser.

The same script loops multiple times and every loop, I need to extract one URL.

Sometimes, when extracting page URL, the URL gets extracted into a .csv file with parentheses around the URL,  This only happens when the script failed on a previous step and did not complete the steps properly (due to page layout changing, etc).  I am needing to extract the URL with no parentheses. Since I do not know the reason why imacros extract command is adding parentheses to the URL, I am trying to find a workaround.

Here is the script that I have to remove parentheses from the URL extract, but it is not working.

I am using:

SET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}

SET LastUrl EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace(/\"/g, \"\");")

'to clear extract memory bank and remove first URL from extract memory bank as I only want modified URL, I run:

SET !EXTRACT NULL

ADD !EXTRACT {{LastURL}}

Parentheses remain.  I am assuming there is something wrong with my EVAL.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

'iMacros' **always** saves lines in csv-files with double quotes ("..."). It's normal! Nevertheless you can try how the following workaround works:

```
SET myFolder {{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}
SET myFile urls_last.txt

SET LastUrl {{!URLCURRENT}}

TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=file:///{{myFolder}}/{{myFile}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT

SET newText EVAL("var text = '{{LastUrl}}' + '<br />' + '{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />'); text;")
URL GOTO=javascript:{document.write("{{newText}}");document.close();}
SAVEAS TYPE=TXT FOLDER={{myFolder}} FILE={{myFile}}
TAB CLOSE
```